# Missing default devise routes after installing devise + activeadmin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, activeadmin

I have recently started rails for a new project. I tried to install devise and activeadmin using [this guide](http://dan.doezema.com/2012/02/how-to-implement-a-single-user-model-with-rails-activeadmin-and-devise/) but the default devise routes seem to be missing. I can go to /users/sign_in to sign in but users/sign_up does not work. Rake routes does not show any routes for registration. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What does your routes.rb look like?

Comment: Just   devise_for :users

  ActiveAdmin.routes(self)

Comment: You ran the active admin devise generator?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason I had to rerun the active admin devise generator